# text changed event not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I need to add 1 event for textbox into my webpage (created in ASP.NET with C#) and I was declared in the Page_Load function and into asp syntax:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textbox1_TextChanged);
    }

public void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox1.Text == "ABCD")
    {
        Image1.Visible = true;
        textbox1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

and into asp page i used this statement:

```
<asp:TextBox Width="200" ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I did debug and found that not execute **textbox1_TextChanged** function

***Why ?***

Comment: you should set title to `TextChanged-event not fired`

Answer (score 11):

you need to set `AutoPostBack` to `true`.
see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2589b44c.aspx) for this:

> To have the TextChanged  event cause
>   an immediate posting, set the TextBox 
>   control's AutoPostBack  property to
>   true.

Comment: But remember: "The TextBox Web server control does not raise an event each time the user enters a keystroke, only when the user leaves the control."

Comment: which is caused by definition of `changed` event of the xhtml-tag :)

Comment: How then does one fire an event on each keystroke?

Comment: @PeteAlvin quick and dirty: attaching to `keyup` and triggering a `change` with eg jQuery. But honestly I see no use in this problem, as this would mean that the response-time has to cope with the strokes-interval (depending on your actual typing speed, something aeound 300 strokes per minute, which means 5 strokes per second, which means a response-time of 200ms).

Comment: in my case i have auto  post back set to true but i dont undertand why the Text changed server side event is not firing when value is set to text box from a dataset,please suggest if i can manually fire that text changed event as that event holds the code to bind the other two drop downs in the page.

Comment: @clarifier yep, you can use `__doPostBack` manually (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback), but this is imho an evil hack :) but, there should already be a `__doPostBack`-invocation in a corresponding html-event. can you verify whether a POST is made and the server-side eventHandler is not triggered (which would be caused by a viewstate, id, ... missmatch - do you build your controls in the correct lifecycle-step)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, better late than never: you declared a method, strictly speaking, a *handler* for the event. But you didn't bind the event to the handler, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox Width="200" ID="textbox1" OnTextChanged="textbox1_TextChanged" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

What you missed: `OnTextChanged="textbox1_TextChanged"`

In other words, your method would never be called because you never told the control that method was a handler for the event.

Answer (score 0):

> I think its also worth noting that the TextChanged event does **not**
>   fire if the text value did not actually change, i.e. you set the text
>   but you set it to the same value it had previously.

Comment: @Rob: thank you for the guidelines.. I will take a look into the suggested link and will pay more attention while reviewing the posts. once again thanks for the suggestions.