# TextChanged event search not work correctly in my code

Tags: c#, mysql

```
    private void dataGridView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        StateTextboxes(true);
        btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
        btnNew.Enabled = false;
        btnClear.Enabled = true;
        StateTextboxes(true);
        DataGridToTextBoxes();
    }
    private void DataGridToTextBoxes()
    {
        txtID.Text = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
        id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
        txtCompany.Text = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["Company"].Value.ToString();
        txtFirstname.Text = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
        txtLastname.Text = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString();
    }
    private void TextChanged_Search_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchData("");
    } 
    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchData(txtSearch.Text);
    }
    private void searchData(string text)
    { 
        using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(stdConnection))
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter msda = new MySqlDataAdapter("BC_Search", mySqlConnection);
            msda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            msda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("_SearchValue", txtSearch.Text);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            msda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

---

Exception Unhandled...

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Table 'bc-database.bdcb' doesn't exist'

### This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
BusinessCardDB.frmMain.searchData(string) in frmMain.cs
BusinessCardDB.frmMain.txtSearch_TextChanged(object, System.EventArgs) in frmMain.cs
[External Code]
BusinessCardDB.Program.Main() in Program.cs

Comment: Stop execution @ msda.Fill(dt);

Comment: You are throwing `throw new NotImplementedException();` at the end of your `searchData` method, which is run by `txtSearch_TextChanged`. You probably want to just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article also: [text changed event not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228650/text-changed-event-not-fired)

Key comments to double check, as these are always required:
"you need to set AutoPostBack to true.".
and:
"<asp:TextBox Width="200" ID="textbox1" **OnTextChanged="textbox1_TextChanged"** runat="server"></asp:TextBox>".